# Error message 'The specified locale is not supported on this operating system.'

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sql-server-ce

I'm creating the database file using the following method.

```
public bool CreateDatabaseFile()
{
    try
    {
        Stream file = File.Create(DBPath);
        file.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when I call

```
 public void CreateDatabaseStruct()
 {
     var queries = new List<string>
     {
         "create table contacts (\"name\" nvarchar,\"emails\" nvarchar);",
         "create table errors (\"code\" int, message nvarchar);"
     };

     foreach (string query in queries)
     {
         var con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
         con.Open();
         var cmd = con.CreateCommand();

         cmd.CommandText = query;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
     }
 }
```

it returns

> The specified locale is not supported on this operating system [LCD - 1].

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

The connection string:

```
 public static readonly string DBPath = "db.sdf";
 public static readonly string connectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0}; Password=...", DBPath);
```

Comment: The problem is probably with your connection string. Can you post it, and also say what you're running this on (Windows Mobile or regular Windows)?

Comment: Can you try running it through a debugger. See which query it is failing on. Also, I notice you didn't put quotes around the `message` column in your `errors` table. This likely isn't an issue since I don't believe that is a keyword, but just wondering why you omitted the quotes for just that column.

Comment: @MusiGenesis:On regular windows. The connection string was posted now. Check out my update.

Comment: the omission of quotes was typo. I fixed it e tried run again, returns same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution is create it using [SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.createdatabase%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifying a [locale ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid.aspx) in your [connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) string via `LCD=####` (where #### is a supported 4 digit LCID number)? If so, are you sure it is supported on your operating system?

If not, perhaps you have your operating system set to a different culture, that is not supported by the database.

Please post your connection string and give some more information on which O/S you are using (as mentioned by @MusiGenesis).

Comment: I posted my connection string. Check out my update. 
it works fine if create the .mdf file using the linqpad I believe that the mistake is in the mode that I create the .mdf file via C#.